# CheckBoxListRow many-to-many in view

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I trying a create in my view, a `CheckBoxListRow` of `YiiBooster`, but this error showing:

```
Property "CModelCollection.cd_perm_per" is not defined.
```

In my _form.php I set a property this:

```
<?php
    $perms = CHtml::listData(Permission::model()->scopeDeleted()->findAll(), 'cd_perm_per', 'ds_titulo_per');
    echo $form->checkBoxListRow($model, 'permission.cd_perm_per',$perms);
    //echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'permission.cd_perm_per',$perms);
?>
```

My relations in Model is:

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'permission' => array(
              self::MANY_MANY,
              'Permission',
              'tb_group_perms(cd_group_grp, cd_perm_per)', 
              'together' => false
         ),    
    );
}
```

Apparently its OK, but not work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve the above problem as follows:

I created a variable called $options in my model which would be stored CheckBoxListRow options. This variable is not in the database it is local.

After this, in my view, I configured my CheckBoxListRow getting this variable $options. Thus the values ​​were correct.

When saving, you must configure the method afterSave() to be saved in the relationship database.

Comment: I understand that English is not your first language, but I have no idea what you are trying to say.  Perhaps some code would help.